# Why does super._update work in 1 function but not the other?

Tags: solidity, erc-1155, import

I am trying to override the _update function in an ERC1155 contract. However I get the following compiler error on my code:

> Member "_update" not found or not visible after argument-dependent lookup in type(contract super MyContract).(9582)

But super._update works in the override function, but not my secondary function. Why is this? I have the error on the line in adjustSftBalances() marked in **, no issues on the _update override.

```
function _update(address from, address to, uint256[] memory ids, uint256[] memory values) internal override virtual {
    // check that batch update is valid.
    if (ids.length != values.length) revert ERC1155InvalidArrayLength(ids.length, values.length);

    // users can only own 1 SFT ID so can only send SFT and token and ERC20 token, should not be transferring more than 2.
    if (values.length > 2) revert ERC1155InvalidArrayLength(ids.length, values.length);
    
    uint256[] memory newIds = new uint256[](1);
    uint256[] memory newValues = new uint256[](1);

    newIds[0] = ERC20_ID;

    if (from != address(0)) {

    }
    for (uint8 i; i < ids.length; i++) {
        if (ids[i] == ERC20_ID) {
            newValues[0] = values[i];
        }
        if (ids[i] > ERC20_ID) {
            newValues[0] = balanceFromRarity(balanceOf(from));
        }
    }
    super._update(from, to, newIds, newValues);

    adjustSftBalances(from);
    adjustSftBalances(to);

}

function adjustSftBalances(address owner) internal virtual {
    if (owner != address(0)) {
        if (_totalSupply[owner] < tokenRarity(owner)) {
            **super._update(address(0), owner, uint160(owner), tokenRarity(owner) - _totalSupply[owner]);**
            // super._mint(owner, uint160(owner), tokenRarity(owner) - _totalSupply[owner], "");
        }
        if (_totalSupply[owner] > tokenRarity(owner)) {
            super._burn(owner, uint160(owner), _totalSupply[owner] - tokenRarity(owner));
        }
        // using your idea of SFTs.
        _totalSupply[owner] = tokenRarity(owner); // if you add the following code they become NFTs > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```

Actually, come to think of it, my first problem seems to be that super._mint was calling my overriden _update function instead of the super._update, but I'm not sure if that was how it should work, I could manually do the super_update but I was hoping super._mint would work using the default functions.

Answer (score 0):

This was just me being dumb. I was trying to pass in uint256 instead of uint256[]. Here's the correct code but another issue (that I'm not sure is a real issue) is that super._burn and super._mint didn't use super._update. Should it?

The fixed code is here:

```
function adjustSftBalances(address owner) public {
    if (owner != address(0)) {
        uint256[] memory ids = new uint256[](1);
        ids[0] = uint160(owner);
        uint256[] memory values = new uint256[](1);
        if (_totalSupply[owner] < tokenRarity(owner)) {
            values[0] = tokenRarity(owner) - _totalSupply[owner];
            super._update(address(0), owner, ids, values);
            // super._mint(owner, uint160(owner), tokenRarity(owner) - _totalSupply[owner], "");
        }
        if (_totalSupply[owner] > tokenRarity(owner)) {
            values[0] = _totalSupply[owner] - tokenRarity(owner);
            super._update(owner, address(0), ids, values);
            // super._burn(owner, uint160(owner), _totalSupply[owner] - tokenRarity(owner));
        }
        // using your idea of SFTs.
        _totalSupply[owner] = tokenRarity(owner); // if you add the following code they become NFTs > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }
}
```